# Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead on discordjs v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I tried to take the server info data with the owner ID,
but when I run the command it gives me an error

```
"Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead
    |
    |   Received:
    |   | '<a:yes:962966293764505620> Server Owner: <@710720629002862632>'"
```

Code:

```js
run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
    let msg = await interaction.reply(`Checking..`);
    let boosts = interaction.guild.premiumSubscriptionCount;
    const ar = ("<a:yes:962966293764505620>")
    let myguild = interaction.guild;
    const members = interaction.guild.members.cache;
    var boostlevel = 0;
  if (boosts >= 2) boostlevel = "1";
  if (boosts >= 7) boostlevel = "2";
  if (boosts >= 14) boostlevel = "3 / ∞";
  let maxbitrate = 96000;
  if (boosts >= 2) maxbitrate = 128000;
  if (boosts >= 7) maxbitrate = 256000;
  if (boosts >= 14) maxbitrate = 384000;
  interaction.guild.owner = await interaction.guild.fetchOwner().then(m => m.user).catch(() => {})

  const emb = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setColor("Aqua")
  .setTitle(`Server info of ${interaction.guild.name}`)
  
    .setImage(interaction.guild.bannerURL({size: 4096}))
    .addFields(`${ar} Server Owner: ${interaction.guild.owner}`)
.setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic : true }))
.setFooter({
    text: `Command Requested by: ${interaction.user.tag}`,
    iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL(),
  })

setTimeout(() => {
    msg.edit({ content: ` `, embeds: [emb] });
  }, 500);
},
};
```

I tried a few solutions online and they still doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

`.addFields()` accepts a series of objects specifying the field title and value.

Your options are to either use `setDescription()` with your current string, or use `addFields()` with an object.

Either of these would be valid:

```js
new EmbedBuilder()
    .setDescription(`${ar} Server Owner: ${interaction.guild.owner}`)
```

```js
new EmbedBuilder()
    .addFields({ name: "Server Owner:", value: interaction.guild.owner })
```